# Saved a file in the wrong location and I cannot retrieve it

Tags: finder, filesystem

I was using ssh-keygen which at some point asked me where I wanted my public key and my identification saved. I typed `\` by mistake and the result was:

> Your identification was saved in \.
>   Your public key was saved in \.pub.

Now I cannot seem to find them. Can I find out what happened and delete those files? I could not find them with `ls -la \`. Actually it starts some type of prompt. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use two back slashes. In the terminal using the bash shell (which it is by default) the backslash character tells bash to allow you to continue typing commands on a new line (hence the prompt you saw).

So if you do `ls -la \\` that should show you the contents of "\"

Likewise `mv \\ fixed` should rename the folder to "fixed"

Comment: "No such file or directory"

Comment: Sounds like it might not be named what you think it was. If you go to the directory where you ran ssh-keygen from and run ls -a do you see any directories that look promising?

Comment: Is it possible there may be an erroneous space in the filename?

Comment: The filename is supposed to be just "\". I guess I could try to look for the .pub file in the whole hard disk.

Comment: I get lot of access denied. It's weird, if you say you want something saved in "\" where is it really saved?

Comment: I don't really see promising directories. @moneyt

Comment: I don't have my mac in front of me right now, but from a linux/bash session I do have, if I run ssh-keygen and tell it to save to "\", it creates two files in my current directory, one named "\" and one named "\.pub". Do you know what working directory you were in when you ran ssh-keygen?

Comment: I feel so retarded. There they are. I looked everywhere else.

Answer (score -1):

You have to enable hidden files to find it then you can search it in spotlight

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Please see [answer].  Good answers should be more than just a single sentence; they'll include the steps necessary to achieve the desired result because the answer will be used by other people, not just the person who originally posted the question.  Feel free to [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/284737/edit) your answer to include additional detail.

Comment: Don't mind the dot at the end. It's just the end of the sentence. identification is not supposed to be hidden. Those are already the full names of the files.